# Using sum of logarithms of primes to prove the number of primes up to $n$ is $O(n/\log n)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I need to show that the number of primes up to $n$ (i.e. $\pi(n)$) is $O(n/\log n)$.
In the previous exercise of this question I proved that ${\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{\pi(n)}\log p_{i}} \leq Cn$ for some constant $C$ (where $p_i$ is the i-th prime number) . I thought I needed to do something like $${\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{\pi(n)}\log p_{i}\geq\sum_{i=\lfloor\pi(n)/2\rfloor}^{\pi(n)}\log p_{i}\geq\frac{\pi(n)}{2}\cdot\log p_{\frac{\pi(n)}{2}}}
  ,$$ and then if I show that $\log p_{\frac{\pi(n)}{2}}=O(\log n)$ then I can prove what I need, but I didn't manage to. I am kinda out of ideas right now. Any clues people?

Comment: This is the Prime Number Theorem. Do you need hints or an answer? I'd say there are plenty of both online

Comment: When I searched some through the net ive found many proofs, but none of them was elementary. The point in my question is to prove it using what I proved in the first exercise. I think it should be pretty elementary. If you have any hints on what I can do from here it will be very helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure how the sum of logs works in to the proof. I know Erdos did an elementary proof (I think there is some controversy or something) and Atle Selberg did an elementary proof. I would suggest trying to find the latter if no one ends up answering. An elementary proof is going to be pretty involved

Comment: @BrentJ: This is much weaker than the prime number theorem.

Comment: @Aryabhata you're absolutely right. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you have from the previous exercise is the [Chebyshev function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function). Let us call it $A(x)$.

You can now use [Abel's identity](http://books.google.com/books?id=iJx1lP9ZcIkC&pg=PA25) to prove what you are seeking.

You have already shown

$$ \sum_{1 \lt k \le x} a(k) = A(x) \le cx$$

(where $a(x) = \log x$ if $x$ is prime, and $0$ otherwise)

(look at the Abel's Identity link to understand the choice of notation)

To use Abel's theorem, we take $f(x) = \frac{1}{\log x}$

And get

$$ \pi(x) = \sum_{1 \lt k \le x} \frac{a(k)}{\log k} \le \frac{cx}{\log x} + \int_{2}^{x} \frac{c}{\log ^2 t}\text{d}t = O\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right)$$

Note: What you are trying to prove is much weaker than the prime number theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Of course partial summation is the most instructive way of doing this. However here is another answer which does not depend on anything:

Assuming that we have proved $$\sum_{p \leq x} \log p \leq C x,$$
for some positive constant $C>0$ and all $x >1,$ we have
$$\Big(\pi(x)-\pi(x^{\frac{1}{2}}) \Big)\log(x^{\frac{1}{2}})
\leq
\sum_{x^{\frac{1}{2}}<p\leq x} \log p
\leq C x.$$
Now using the trivial bound $\pi(x^{\frac{1}{2}})\leq x^{\frac{1}{2}},$
we get that
$$\pi(x)\leq 2C \frac{x}{\log x}+x^{\frac{1}{2}} =O(\frac{x}{\log x}).
$$